# Display alert dialog from custom helper class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom class to check network connection and show dialog if not connected.  However whenever it is not connected it crashes on `alertDialog.show();` Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Below is the custom class.

```
package com.garciaericn.goodeats.helpers;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class CheckConnection {

    Context mContext;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;

    public CheckConnection(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Return true if connected
            return true;
        } else {
            // Display dialog for user to connect, with intent to wifi settings
            showConnectionFailedDialog();
        }
        // Return false by default
        return false;
    }

    private void showConnectionFailedDialog() {
        // Display dialog for user to connect, with intent to wifi settings
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .setTitle("No Network Connection")
                .setMessage("Please enable wifi data from.");

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Wifi Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent mobileSettingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(mobileSettingsIntent);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Mobile Network", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent mobileSettingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(mobileSettingsIntent);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

The error stack I get is:

```
11-22 17:29:15.895  19326-19326/com.garciaericn.goodeats E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.garciaericn.goodeats, PID: 19326
        android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:566)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
        at com.garciaericn.goodeats.helpers.CheckConnection.showConnectionFailedDialog(CheckConnection.java:76)
        at com.garciaericn.goodeats.helpers.CheckConnection.isConnected(CheckConnection.java:35)
        at com.garciaericn.goodeats.login.LoginFragment.onConnectionFailed(LoginFragment.java:185)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.gn(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.d(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$4.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.e.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.g(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$b.gU(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

It's being called from:

package com.garciaericn.goodeats.login;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.garciaericn.goodeats.R;
import com.garciaericn.goodeats.helpers.CheckConnection;
import com.garciaericn.goodeats.main.FavoritesActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    public static final String TAG = "com.garciaericn.goodeats.login.LoginFragment.TAG";

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final int RC_LOGGED_IN = 1034553;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_OUT = 34458392;
    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    /* Store the connection result from onConnectionFailed callbacks so that we can
     * resolve them when the user clicks sign-in.
     */
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private boolean mSignedIn;
    private CheckConnection checkConnection;

    public LoginFragment() {
    }

    public static LoginFragment getInstance() {
        return new LoginFragment();
    }

    private void signOut() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//        checkConnection = new CheckConnection(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        checkConnection = new CheckConnection(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) view.findViewById(R.id.g_plus_login);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_sign_out:
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checkConnection.isConnected();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.g_plus_login:
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mSignInClicked = true;
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
                break;
            default:
                // If default action is needed.
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mSignedIn = true;
        // User is connected


        String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), accountName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        String accountID = GoogleAuthUtil.getAccountId(getActivity(), accountName);
//        try {
//            accountID = GoogleAuthUtil.getAccountId(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),accountName);
//        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

//        if (accountID != null) {
//            // TODO: createLocalAccount() = Store account name and id with DB of restaurants
//        }


        // Launch main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FavoritesActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
            // 'sign-in'.
            mConnectionResult = connectionResult;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                resolveSignInError();
            }

        }
        checkConnection.isConnected();
//        if (!checkConnection.isConnected()) {
//            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No network connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        }

    }

    public void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                getActivity().startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == RC_LOGGED_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RC_SIGN_OUT) {
                signOut();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Change mContext to a context where you have the parent view inflated.

Comment: are you calling this from UI thread? Can you show from where the function is being called?

Comment: This is where I moved it...still crashes `@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    
            checkConnection = new CheckConnection(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    
            SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) view.findViewById(R.id.g_plus_login);
            signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
            signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    
            return view;
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception most likely occurs if you use an Application Context instead of an Activity Context to initialize the Dialog.

Do you initialize your `CheckConnection` object with `getApplicationContext()` or alike? If so you should pass an Activity as your Context.

Edit: Taking your code from your comment, you just have to change

```
checkConnection = new CheckConnection(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
checkConnection = new CheckConnection(getActivity());
```